# visual studio 2008 - full framework toolbox instead of compact framework toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, opennetcf

I am trying to create my first project with opennetcf.ioc. I am trying to create SmartPart control that inherits from another SmartPart.

So I create UserControl1 that inherits from OpenNETCF.IoC.UI.SmartPart. Then I create UserControl2 that inherits from UserControl1. And here comes a problem: when designing UserControl2 the compact framework components disappeared from toolbox. Instead there are components from full framework. When I design UserControl1 the compact framework components are available as normal.

How to solve this issue? I have tried:

- resetting the toolbox
- deleting the hidden toolbox files
- resetting VS using the following command: "devenv.exe /setup /resetuserdata"
- resetting it using "cmd /c start /wait devenv /setup /resetuserdata /selfreg /resetskippkgs"

**EDIT:**
The problem disappears when using Compact Framework 2.0 instead of 3.5.

Comment: You might try using a 3.5 build of the IoC library with the 3.5 app.  Not sure if it will solve it but that's what I'd try.

Comment: When I create project that targets 3.5 framework the resulting library still has v2.0.50727 runtime version - the same as when I create project for 2.0 framework. Why is that?

Comment: I have found some workaround: when designing UserControl2 make the UserControl1 inheriting not from SmartPart but from UserControl. When finished designing switch back to SmartPart.

Comment: Yeah, now that you mention it, I think that's what I do as well.  I use the IoC framework on the desktop, too, which is what I've been doing lately, so I'd forgotten.